# .Net window service and ASP.NET web form has same code to send SMS

Tags: c#

I am writing Send SMS code in .Net window service and asp.net web forms for sending SMS to client But i am facing problem in send SMS per second to MBLOX url. Problem is that when i am using web form, it sends 60 SMS/S to Mblox url but in window service it sends only 4 SMS/S but both has same code.Please give me solution what should i do that case.

I am using below code in asp.net web forms and window service. But web forms takes very short time and window service takes very long time. but i would like to use window service.

```
public void SendMessageUsingThread(string messagetext)
{


    StreamReader objSreamReader = new StreamReader("D:/ExpressText/TestApplication/WindowService/TestWindowService/TestWindowService/Numbers.txt");
    string MobileNumber = objSreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] NumberList = MobileNumber.Split(',');
    Dictionary<int, string> objdictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberList.Length; i++)
    {
        objdictionary.Add(i, NumberList[i].ToString().Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ').Trim());
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < objdictionary.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(e => { SendMTMessageNew(objdictionary[j], messagetext); });
    }
}



public void SendMTMessageNew(string mobileNumber, string messagetext)
{
    string requestId = string.Empty;
    string OutXml = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string formatedMessage = formate4infoMessage(messagetext);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //int MessageCounter = GetMessageCounter();
        string MessageCounter = mobileNumber.Substring(4);

        sb.Append("<NotificationRequest Version=\"3.5\">");
        sb.Append("<NotificationHeader>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<PartnerName>{0}</PartnerName>", "XXXXXXXX");
        sb.AppendFormat("<PartnerPassword>{0}</PartnerPassword>", "XXXXXXXX");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Username>{0}</Username>", "XXXXXXXX");
        sb.Append("</NotificationHeader>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<NotificationList BatchID=\"{0}\">", MessageCounter);
        sb.AppendFormat("<Notification SequenceNumber=\"{0}\" MessageType=\"{1}\" >", MessageCounter, "SMS");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Message>{0}</Message>", formatedMessage);
        sb.AppendFormat("<Profile>{0}</Profile>", _ProfileId);// If u have single product form mblox u need to pass -1
        sb.AppendFormat("<SenderID Type=\"Shortcode\">{0}</SenderID>", XXXXXXX);
        sb.Append("<ExpireDate></ExpireDate>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Operator></Operator>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<Tariff></Tariff>");
        sb.Append("<Subscriber>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<SubscriberNumber>{0}</SubscriberNumber>", "XXXXXXX");
        sb.Append("</Subscriber>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<ServiceId>{0}</ServiceId>", "XXXXXXX");
        sb.Append("</Notification>");
        sb.Append("</NotificationList>");
        sb.Append("</NotificationRequest>");


        OutXml = sb.ToString();

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://{0}", Host));


        byte[] requestBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OutXml);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;

        req.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy(); ;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

        Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string backstr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        res.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CreatelogfileForMloxResponseXML(ex.Message + "--------------" + "SendMTMessageNew");
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't answer this. Probably it's just a configuration issue, for example a proxy server that's present in one situation and missing in another. It's not your code, and not the fact it's in a Windows Service.

Comment: in web form is take less time as compare to window service.i would like to know why it takes long time in window service.